# Styling a string with a span jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to style a text which the client would type into a textfield. The text should be styled as it shows into my html. I have 3 switch statements . 
How can i style it using a span.

```
var text = myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text;

switch( myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text.length ) {
    case 1:
        layer_InHTML= text; // allows what the user types to show in my html 
        //one letter should be big.
        break;
    case 2: 
        layer_InHTML = "<span ='font-size:2.5em;'>text.charAt(0)</span>"+charAt(1) 
        // this does not work. How can I improve this? 
        //two letters should be big
    case 3: 
        //three letters should be big. 
        break;
```

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make big all letters, except last one (which goes from the case 2 in your switch statement), you can use just the following code without any switch statements:

```
var text = myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text;
layer_InHTML = "<span style='font-size:2.5em;'>"+text.substr(0,text.length-1)+"</span>"+text.substr(text.length-1);
```

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/25s0pa0s/).